# How to show svg picture as a cursor

Tags: svg, cursors

We have cursors in design  in form of circle. But when we took svg picture from design and reconvert it to .cur format we got cursor with smashed edges.
We need sharp circle
What can we do?

Comment: Please create an [mcve] so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Dont's take svg picture from design and just google the image you want. Just google a file you want and save it as yourchoice.cur name and use it in your code.